# how to configure adfs with saml 2.0 protocol to work with active client (non-browser based)

Tags: wif, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, ws-federation, ws-trust

Is there a way to use adfs with saml 2.0 protocol to work with active client (non-browser based) service provider?
Is there any equivalence to WSTrust (on WS-Federation protocol) for saml 2.0 protocol? 
If it is possible can you give me an example?

Comment: OAuth is the WS-Trust of the SAML world...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your channel with an ActAs token and pass that token along for the active to work properly.